# Angular input decimal

Tags: angular, angular-material

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkq1e7-hhqjrp?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-clearable-example.html

I have typical `<input matInput type="number">` (reactive from + material).

When I insert 1000 I see "1000" but in input I want formatted value "1 000,00".

Here is what I have done so far :

```html
<input matInput type="number"  (input)="formatInput($event.target)">
```

```js
formatInput(input: any) {
  const value = input.value.replace(/,/g, "");
  const formattedValue = Number(value).toLocaleString("en-US", {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: true
  });
  input.value = formattedValue;
}
```

I can not install anything in this app

Comment: Your `input` type is set to `number` it won't accept your formatted string.

Comment: thanks but any suggestion how rite formatinput method any example?

Comment: Remove the `type="number"` and make sure that your function rejects non-numeric values.

Comment: The "Angular way" to accomplish this is through Internationalization. Docs here: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview